# pip doesn't connect, can't install anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to use pip install on a raspberry pi 4 (Raspian Buster) but I've been getting the same errors for a while now, I've tried a lot of common fixes but none worked.

What I've already tried:
- apt-get update and upgrade
- uninstalled and installed opensll
- uninstalled and installed pip and pip3 several times
- uninstalled and installed python and python3 (with restarts)
- I'm not being blocked by a firewall or anything (I'm using a raspberry pi 4 connected directly to the router at home)

Example outputs, same result with pip/pip3, using sudo and not and also tried using the flag "--default-timeout=120", always get the same errors

```
$ sudo pip3 install  pyopenssl
Collecting pyopenssl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/pyopenssl/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyopenssl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyopenssl

$ sudo pip3 install docker-compose
Collecting docker-compose
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/docker-compose/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/docker-compose/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/docker-compose/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/docker-compose/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/docker-compose/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement docker-compose (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for docker-compose
```

Whenever pip has to connect to anything I get this same kind of errors, any ideia as why this is happening?

Comment: Use `pip -v` to increase verbosity. Maybe verbose output will provide more information.

Comment: Try to update your pip, `easy_install --upgrade pip`